# The version of play-services is no longer being updated

Tags: android, android-studio

I get an error after updating Android Studio to 2.3.1.
The latest version of play-services-measurement is 8.4.0 and can not be updated anymore.

[image: error message 1]

[image: error message 2]

Comment: The error message clearly stating that "Install Repository and sync project". Why don't you do that?

Comment: please show your root build.gradle file ?

Answer (score 0):

Need to update Google Repository in the SDK Manager.

And update your classpath in project level gradle to `classpath com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}
```